# onSnapshot listener create many 'List' requests

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an app using `Nextjs` and `firebase/firestore` as my stack.

I have a component in which I need to read some data from firestore. I wanted to use real time updates to I used the `onSnapshot` function inside of a `useEffect` call.

Here is the code -

```
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
  const q = query(
    collection(db, "/categories/"),
    where("uid", "==", auth.currentUser?.uid)
  );
  return onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    console.log("ran onsnapshot");
    const categories = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data(),
    })) as Category[];
    setCategories(categories);
  });
}, []);
```

Everything works fine, but the problem is that when I use the firestore emulator locally, I can see that every time I create a new document in the collection, then I can see that about 50 different `LIST` requests are sent to the DB. In my browser's console I can see that the `'ran onsnapshot'` only gets logged once, so there aren't multiple snapshot listeners.

[image: screen shot of many LIST requests]

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this just the behavior of the `onSnapshot` listener?

EDIT:

As per @KonradLinkowski's comment I changed the `useEffect` function to return a function that just calls the unsubscribe that is returned from `onSnapshot` like so -

```
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
  const q = query(
    collection(db, "/categories/"),
    where("uid", "==", auth.currentUser?.uid)
  );
  const unsub = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    console.log("ran onsnapshot");
    const categories = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data(),
    })) as Category[];
    setCategories(categories);
  });
  return () => unsub();
}, []);
```

And that seemed to solve the problem. Any insights on why that matters?

Comment: `return` in `useEffect` is reserved for unmount handler.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I do know that, but is there a difference from what I am returning than creating a function that just calls the unsubscribe function that `onSnapshot` returns?

Comment: You are r ight.

Comment: Is this code a list item or a parent of list items?

Comment: This if code from the parent. I use data from `categories` to render a list of child components